# GROUP CONCAT with ORDER in MEMSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, singlestore

Here is a toy example:

```
CREATE TABLE TEST
(
    ID INT,
    AGG NVARCHAR(20),
    GRP NVARCHAR(20)
);

INSERT INTO TEST VALUES
    (1, 'AB', 'X'), (2, 'BC', 'X'), (3, 'AC', 'X'),
    (4, 'EF', 'Y'), (5, 'FG', 'Y'), (6, 'DC', 'Y'),
    (7, 'JI', 'Z'), (8, 'IJ', 'Z'), (9, 'JK', 'Z');
```

Now, I would like to do this (this is a valid code in MySQL, but not in MEMSQL):

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*),
    SUM(ID),
    GROUP_CONCAT(AGG ORDER BY AGG),
    GRP
FROM TEST
GROUP BY GRP
```

So that the output looks like this **(Required Output)**:

```
3   6   AB,AC,BC    X
3   15  DC,EF,FG    Y
3   24  IJ,JI,JK    Z
```

Note that the **values in the third column are sorted for each row**. My output looks like this **(Current *Wrong* Output)**:

```
3   6   BC,AB,AC    X
3   15  DC,EF,FG    Y
3   24  IJ,JI,JK    Z
```

Compare each row in the third column, the lists are sorted.

However, since the above query is not valid in MEMSQL, I have to remove the `ORDER BY AGG` part in `GROUP_CONCAT` which causes the third column to not be sorted.

As per the [documentation of `GROUP_CONCAT`](https://docs.memsql.com/sql-reference/v6.0/group_concat/), the expression can also be a function, however, there is no built in function to sort. I have tried many combinations of `SELECT ... ORDER BY` statements in `GROUP_CONCAT` without success. Is this impossible to do, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

I think this works for my case.

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*),
    SUM(T.ID),
    GROUP_CONCAT(T.AGG),
    T.GRP
FROM (
    SELECT 
        *,
        RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY GRP ORDER BY AGG) AS R
    FROM TEST
) T
GROUP BY T.GRP
ORDER BY T.R
```

It is rather convoluted, so I hope someone can suggest an improvement.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*),
    SUM(ID),
    GROUP_CONCAT(AGG),
    GRP
FROM TEST
GROUP BY GRP
ORDER BY GROUP_CONCAT(AGG)
```

Comment: I guess I was not clear in the question, I will edit it. However, I want the values in each row in the column to be sorted, not the output sorted by that column. Basically, I am getting output like this: `BC,AB,AC`, which is not sorted. I want the output like this `AB,AC,BC`.